# AS3 - addchild from stage to movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I just tried to add the movieclip "box" to the "container.holder". Both movieclips are on stage. 
Nothing happends with this script.

```
container.holder.addChild(box);
```

What do I miss there?

Comment: Did you check box.x and box.y ?

Comment: Could you able to show a map?

Comment: is container.holder is two movieclips?? holder is another movieclip that is in the container??

Comment: Yes, holder is another movieclip that is in the container.

Comment: try this MovieClip(root).container.holder.addChild(box);

Comment: OK that seems to work but the "box" is not at the default 0,0 position of the "holder" movieclip. Instead it keeps the original postion from the stage.

Comment: for that you need set movieclip registraion point to top_left at the time of creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

Maybe you forgot to stage.removeChild(box)?

### Old

When you add `box` in `holder` you have to convert its "global" (stage) position to a "local" (holder) position using the [globalToLocal method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#globalToLocal%28%29).

```
var global : Point = new Point(box.x, box.y);
var local : Point = container.holder.globalToLocal(global);
container.holder.addChild(box);
box.x = local.x;
box.y = local.y;
```

Comment: If I run your script nothing happends - the movieclips remain on the position on stage. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of my post, to keep the position of the box (I though it was your problem...). What do you want your script to do then ?

Comment: Sorry for my english. I just want to grab the "box" movieclip that lies on stage (not library) and put it than into the "container.holder" movieclip.